# AWS AppSync wait for DynamoDB Streams Lambda function before resolving sub-resource

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, amazon-dynamodb-streams, aws-appsync

I have GraphQL schema similar to the following. There are multiple Alphas in a single Bravo, and they each have a reference to each other. (A Bravo can get its Alphas, and an Alpha can get its Bravo.)

```
type Alpha {
  id: ID!
  value: Int!
  bravo: Bravo!
}

type Bravo {
  value: Int!
  alphas: [Alpha!]!
}

input InputAlpha {
  value: Int!
}

type Mutation {
  putAlpha(alpha: InputAlpha): Alpha!
}

schema {
  mutation: Mutation
}
```

As you can tell, both types have a value. The value of Alpha is arbitrary, but the value of Bravo is the sum of its associated Alphas. For performance (and cost) reasons, the Bravo's value is cached in the DynamoDB table and modified whenever an Alpha is updated.

Alphas are updated with a simple AppSync DynamoDB `PutItem` resolver, with the intention being that the value of its Bravo would be updated by a Lambda function watching the table's stream. This works well for the most part; I can put Alphas with random values, and I can get the value of their Bravo.

The problem occurs when I try to request the value of the Bravo in the same request. (The Lambda function takes some time to update it from the stream.)

```
mutation putAlpha {
  putAlpha(alpha: {
      value: 10
  }) {
    id
    value
    bravo {
      value
    }
  }
}
```

Naturally this returns the old cached `value` of `bravo`, because the Lambda function hasn't been run by the time the Bravo is resolved.

Is there any way to wait until the DynamoDB stream's Lambda function has fired before resolving `bravo` or perhaps make the `PutItem` operation synchronous?

The only alternative I can think of is to make the `putAlpha` resolver a Lambda function instead of a simple resolver and do the Bravo updating logic in there.

Is this kind of Lambda continuously updating a cache value normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your client should be aware that Bravo's value is calculated in the background.
If that's not a tradeoff that you can make, consider moving Bravo's update logic to putAlpha mutation.
(To avoid race conditions you can use UpdateExpression's ADD action.)

One way would be to update Bravo's value through you API in your stream and subscribe to Bravo's updates in your client. It is possible to run aws-appsync in Lambda though you need to provide window, xhr etc.

Couple of other ways:

1. You can increase Bravo's value in client's cache instead of taking it from putAlpha's response.
2. You can retrieve Bravo's value once it's updated.
   (It will probably be updated after some seconds. Perhaps you have a way to verify if this Alpha was applied to Bravo, storing last Alpha's update time to Bravo could work.)

Comment: Thanks, I think doing the update in the `putAlpha` mutation in the Lambda function is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you know what the next value of Bravo should be when you run updateAlpha (e.g. you don't need to read the other Alphas), you can use BatchPutItem to update both tables.

If not, I don't believe AppSync fully supports this use case right now.

To make it work, you need to wait for the Bravo record to get updated before reading it. I think the easiest way, at the moment, would be to use a Lambda function.

Some other things you could try (they're a bit hacky):

1. Make the putAlpha mutation resolver spin in a loop for a specified amount of time until the stream updates the Bravo record.
2. Add a resolver on Alpha.bravo which waits X amount in the request mapping template before reading from the table.
3. Add a resolver on Bravo.value which queries all the Alphas, sums up their values, and then returns the summed value. This kind of defeats the purpose of storing a value on Bravo.

I don't think you can use a sleep in the resolver's, but you can use loops: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html#loops

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to go with a `putAlpha` Lambda function resolver that handled the update to Bravo. There's some interesting ideas here though.